# put specific data in ajax request using fetch() or XMR/any_other_type_of_ajax-request, like the same in jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I have a simple request using **jQuery ajax()**

```
getJson() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                rss_url: 'https://news.yandex.ru/sport.rss',
                api_key: 'lpdljjsrqnqsmtp0zqbngg0yjoeykl0iiw6f5lvnf',
                count: 15
            }
        })
        // other code
}
```

It is a request to a service, that takes rss (from rss_url) and returns JSON. Everything is fine, but now I have to make the same ajax request without jQuery.
This request has to look like this with all params (because service understands only theese params).

I tried do the same using **fetch()** :

```
getJson() {
    let url = 'http://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json';
    let config = {
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'rss_url': 'https://news.yandex.ru/politics.rss',
            'api_key': 'lpdljjsrqnqsmtp0zqbngg0yjoeykl0iiw6f5lvnf',
            count: 15
        }
    }

    fetch(url, config)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

tried to use **XMLHttpRequest**

```
  getJson() {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      let jsonData = JSON.stringify({
                rss_url: 'https://news.yandex.ru/politics.rss',
                api_key: 'lpdljjsrqnqsmtp0zqbngg0yjoeykl0iiw6f5lvnf',
                count: 15
      });
      xhr.open('GET', 'http://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
          xhr.onload = () => {
              if(xhr.status === 200) {
                  console.log(xhr.response);
              }
              else {
                  console.log('error ' + xhr.status);
              }
          };
          xhr.onerror = () => {
              console.log('Connection error');
          }
      };
      xhr.send(jsonData);

  }
```

As a result - error
{"status":"error","message":"`rss_url` parameter is required"}

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You know there's this cool place over at Mozilla that i dare say has documentation on these sorts of things... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Yes. I know.
I've taken this example fetch(url, config) from there.
But thank you. @Darkrum

Comment: If you did read it correct you would have noticed that there is no data object on requests only body and also GET cannot have a body.

Comment: The reason your jQuery ajax works is because GET with a body is converted into a query string even though it should just fail all together but that's there way of dealing with it.

Comment: @Darkrum
So, now I've understood, how jQuery `GET` works. Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a `GET` with those params, just put them in the URL you give to `fetch()` or XHR:

```
let url = 'http://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://news.yandex.ru/politics.rss&api_key=lpdljjsrqnqsmtp0zqbngg0yjoeykl0iiw6f5lvnf&count=15';
```